# Explicating a step found in proof of Theorem 6.10 Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

This question concerns a step in the proof of Theorem 6.10 found on pages 126-7:

> Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ has only finitely many points
> of discontinuity on $[a,b]$, and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point
> at which $f$ is discontinuous. Then $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\varepsilon>0$. Put $M=\sup|f(x)|$, let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous. Since $E$ is finite and
> $\alpha$ is continuous over $E$, we can cover $E$ by finitely many
> disjoint intervals $[u_j,v_j]\subset[a,b]$ such the
> $\alpha(v_j)-\alpha(u_j)<\varepsilon$.  Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point $E\cap(a, b)$ lies in the interior of some $[u_j,v_j]$.
>
> Remove the segments $(u_j,v_j)$ from $[a,b]$. The remaining set $K$ is
> compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, and there exists
> $\delta>0$ such that $|f(s)-f(t)|<\varepsilon$ if $s,t\in K$ and
> $|s-t|<\delta$.
>
> Now form a partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ as follows:
> each $u_j$ occurs in $P$. Each $v_j$ occurs in $P$. No point of any
> segment $(u_j,v_j)$ occurs in $P$. If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the
> $u_j$, then $\Delta x_i<\delta$.
>
> $\ldots$

My question concerns the partition $P$. I am not convinced about its existence. Therefore I would like to explicate its construction.

Begin by fixing an $\varepsilon>0$. Since $E\subset[a,b]$ is finite, we can write $E=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$. As $\alpha$ is continuous over $E$, for each $1\leq i\leq n$, there exists $\delta_i>0$ such that
$$(\forall y)(y\in[a,b]\land|y-x_i|<\delta_i\implies|f(y)-f(x_i)|<\varepsilon).$$
Fix $j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$. Presumably, Rudin wants to define $u_j=x_j-\frac{\delta_j}{2}$ and $v_j=x_j+\frac{\delta_j}{2}$ (or something similar), unless $x_j\in\{a,b\}$ in which case we can make suitable arrangements. Then, since $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing, we have that $\alpha(v_j)-\alpha(u_j)\geq 0$ and we conclude that $\alpha(v_j)-\alpha(u_j)<\varepsilon$. This much I understand.

Now, we come to constructing $P$. We need to come up with a rule which gives a sequence $a=y_0\leq y_1\leq\ldots\leq y_k=b$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$, such that $\Delta y_i<\delta$ and $y_i\not\in(u_i,v_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, and $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots, v_n\}\subset\{y_0,\ldots,y_k\}$.

Can someone please help me explicitly define $P$? What's the best way to approach it?

Comment: Choose a subpartition in each of the subinterval $[v_j,u_{j+1}]$.

Comment: Few nitpicking comments: $f$ is continuous over $E$, but $\alpha$ is (typo, I presume?). Next, I suggest you don't reuse variables (e.g., Rudin's $x_i$ and your $x_i$ mean different things).

Comment: @Zuza Yes a few typos, thanks for pointing them out. I fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

Order the discontinuities E in an increasing order and let them be contained in $\{ (u_j, v_j) \}_{j=1}^k$. Therefore, for example, $v_1 \le u_2$. Then, simply subdivide each of the intervals $[a, u_1], [v_1, u_2], [v_2, u_3], \ldots, [v_k, b]$ with sufficiently many (increasingly indexed) points $P = \{ x_i \}_i$ until $\Delta x_i < \delta$ for all $i$.